# Getting Error while trying to connect to SVN repository

Tags: svn, repository

When I am trying to connect to my SVN repository on some remote server I am getting an error.

> Unable to Connect to a repository URL 'svn://path/to/my/repository/'.
> Can't connect to host. No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are several *methods* Subversion uses to talk to the Subversion server:

- Using httpd
- Using svnserve
- Direct file access.

So, the first thing we need to know is how are you talking to your Subversion repository? Did you set it up? If you did, are you running `svnserve` in order to act as a server? Or, did you configure your Apache httpd web server to act as the Subversion repository server? If you didn't set it up, who did?

Let's go through the basics:

### File Access

You created the Subversion repository in /usr/share/svn/repository using the `svnadmin create` command. You didn't do anything else. In that case, you would access your repository as:

```
$ svn co file:///usr/share/svn/repository
```

Note that the URL protocol is `file://` and not `svn://`.

### SVNSERVE Access

Let's say that your repository sits on machine *alpha*, and there's only a single repository on *alpha*

The format for the URL is:

```
$ svn co svn://alpha
```

Note that the protocol is `svn://` and the first thing after the protocol is the machine name. The `svnserve` is a simple, easy to setup, and fast server for Subversion repositories. I use it even if I could use `file://` just because I don't have to keep giving the full path name each  time.

If you setup your own Subversion repository, you can use the `svnserve` to run it. It uses port 3690 by default, and only a single `svnserve` instance can run on a machine using that port (you can change the port, but it's messy and I don't want to go into now).

To use the svnserve server, you need to do a few very minor things:

- **Setup the `svnserve.conf` File**: Under your repository is a directory called `conf`. In this directory is a file called `svnserve.conf`. You need to find the line that begins with `passed` and remove the pound signs (aka sharps or octothorps) in front of the line: It's around line #20.

Just change:

```
### password-db = passwd
```

to:

```
password-db = passwd
```

- **Setup the `passwd file:** In the same directory as the`svnserve.conf`file is another file called`passwd`. Edit this file, to include an account for you. There's two examples in the file for`harry`and`sally`. Create one for you. This will be your user name (no spaces) and your password. When you checkout or commit files in Subversion, you'll use this.

### http Access

You can setup an Apache httpd web server (the most popular web server on the Internet) to also be used as a Subversion server. It's a complex process, and I'm not going into here. However, if someone has set it up for you, the URL would be split into several parts:

- The `http://` protocol declaration
- The name of the server
- The virtual directory used for the repository (there can be multiple repositories)
- The directory you're checking out.

Let's say the machine is named *alpha*, and you want to checkout from the `foo` project's repository:

```
$ svn co http://alpha/foo/trunk
```

I highly suggest you edit your question and include some more details. For example, where does your Subversion repository reside? Is it on your current system? Did you setup your Subversion repository, or did an administrator do it for you? Show us the exact command and error message you're getting too.

Otherwise, your question will probably be closed. See the Stackoverflow [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

Actually my service of SVN was not running. So due this the server was not responding.

Comment: Exactly! As simple as that. ( `svnserve -d -r /path/to/repo`)